# Spring Integration http outbound-gateway

Tags: xsd, schema, spring-integration

I'm trying to use the Spring Integration http outbound gateway, but I seem to be getting  schema-related errors. The errors are:

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'expected-response-type' is not allowed to appear in element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'. sprint-servlet.xml  /sprint/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 28
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'url' is not allowed to appear in element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'.    sprint-servlet.xml  /sprint/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 28
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'http-method' is not allowed to appear in element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'.    sprint-servlet.xml  /sprint/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 28
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'reply-timeout' is not allowed to appear in element 'int-http:outbound-gateway'.  sprint-servlet.xml  /sprint/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 28
```

It appears that the XSD does not accept these attributes. However, I've simply copy / pasted this from the Spring Integration docs. Here's the relevant part of my XML config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">



<!-- Spring Integration stuff -->
<int:channel id="requests">
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="replies"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="example"
  request-channel="requests"
  url="http://localhost/test"
  http-method="POST"
  expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
  charset="UTF-8"
  reply-timeout="1234"
  reply-channel="replies"/>
```

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Is it an issue from STS or after the running of application ? And be sure to use correct Spring Integration version: http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration

Comment: You need to put the Spring Integration jars on your classpath (http and core).

Comment: i have tried producing the same issue and found error againt 'reply-timeout' attribute only.

Comment: by the way, which version of spring integration you are using?

Comment: Hello All, I'm using the following version of Spring - 3.0.2.RELEASE. When I try and create a Java-based application (aka with a "main"), I get an XSD error, so I've had to turn validation off.

Comment: Also, I believe all jars are in the path - I am able to instantiate Spring Integration classes in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Add `spring-integration-http` and `spring-integration-core` to your dependencies.

Should work

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found the answer here 
[Why does Spring Integration have several XML schemas, and which one should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137824/why-does-spring-integration-have-several-xml-schemas-and-which-one-should-i-use)

Basically, the schema without a version is the version 1.0 schema. Point your schema to your version of spring integration like so

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-4.1.xsd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using STS - I'm using the standard Eclipse IDE. I'm not sure if STS helps with the classpath, but I simply can't get that to work for me. I ended up having to extract the XSDs from the .jar files and hosting them myself. Hopefully, the good folks at Spring Integration will post the most recent XSDs on the Spring site sometime soon. Until that time, however, I've got a workaround in place.