# Version-less schema references

Tags: spring-integration

With reference to [Answer on multiple schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11138350/1892382)
And following all examples, which use version-less schema references within the spring integration context files.

There seems to be an issue with some of the schemas online. For example:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
```

is not the same as:

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.2.xsd`

Which at the time of writing is the latest version. Now this does not causes any problems when running the application, but eclipse complains about lots of attributes. To fix it, I simply force reference to version 4.2

So, is there something wrong with the schema, ie are they out of date?

Or am I doing this wrong? Here are the before and after schema refs:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd">
```

After:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream-4.2.xsd">
```

Further to this:`http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd` references `http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-1.0.xsd`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for historical reasons, some of the versionless schemas on the internet have to reflect the 1.0 schemas, otherwise existing applications that are using 1.0.x versions will fail; there may be users that still use those old versions.

Versions of Spring Integration since 1.0.4 access the correct schema version from the classpath so this is not an issue at runtime.

Spring-aware IDEs (such as STS, IDEA) know how Spring resolves the correct schema from the classpath. Eclipse without the Spring plugins does not, but you can set up schema mappings in the preferences to map the versionless schema to the right schema.

We have an [open JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2452?focusedCommentId=117894&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-117894) to add a comment to that effect to those schemas that are affected by this issue.

We apologize for the inconvenience, but there's nothing we can do without breaking old apps. We just don't know if there's a production app out there on 1.0.3.

Comment: Thanks Gary, very well explained