# Version-less schemas for Spring Integration points to an old version of the XSD

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, spring-integration

In this post (from 2012),

[Why does Spring Integration have several XML schemas, and which one should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137824/why-does-spring-integration-have-several-xml-schemas-and-which-one-should-i-use)

Gary R. wrote that for "spring-integration" and "spring-integration-file":

> The version-less schema on the internet is an old 1.0 schema; we need
>   to figure out how we can change that, but it's not simple, for various
>   reasons,

I checked them today, and they both still point to the 1.0 schema.

Are there any plans for the version-less schema to point to the latest (current) 4.2 version? Or do we continue using the versioned schema for these two?

Answer (score 2):

We have added comments stating why the internet-hosted version-less schemas for certain modules have to continue to point to the 1.0 schema versions.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd

```
<!--
   +++++ IMPORTANT +++++

 This schema is for the 1.0 version of Spring Integration Core. We cannot update it to the current schema
 because that will break any applications using 1.0.3 or lower. For subsequent versions, the unversioned
 schema is resolved from the classpath and obtained from the jar.
 Please refer to github:

 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/config/xml

 for the latest schema. 
-->
```

Spring does **not** use the internet-hosted schemas at runtime.

You can safely use version-less schemas in your application and the correct one will be used.